# Doas keeps asking me for password

Tags: linux, sudo, system-administration, gentoo

I installed Doas as a replacement for sudo on my Gentoo machine. I followed the documentation [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Doas) and my `/etc/doas.conf` looks like this:

```
permit persist :wheel
```

I have also restarted the system. However, it still asks me for the password every time I use `doas`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable `persist` while you are compiling. Set `persist` use flag and it will work. If you have `(persist)` while you are compiling, you have to unmask the `app-admin/doas` first.

Comment: This is the solution for anyone wondering on Gentoo.

Comment: I'm using Debian, installed `doas` with apt, and I have not the slightest idea what I just read in this answer...

Comment: TLDR: if it doesn't work, the package maintainer has to make a change, unless you're on Gentoo, where you can make that change yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Make below changes in the doas configuration.

```
permit nopass ::wheel
```

or
allow user and dont require a password to execute commands as root

```
permit nopass keepenv :username2
```

Reference URL

https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/doas-tips-sudo-alternative.69409/

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it didn't ask me for a password. However, I wonder why `persist` doesn't work.

Comment: Check the config file and up like the answers

Comment: Is there a way I can make it ask for my password once and then keep me logged in for a while? In the documentation it says `persist` does the desired behavior but it does not work.

Comment: This is not the same as `persist`. Instead it simply never asks for the password.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

`permit persist username as root`

Comment: This doesn't work. The only difference in your config from the original is the `as root` part, which prevents `doas -u differentuser command` from working